# In Mac how do I signal end of file (EOF) on the shell

Tags: windows, macos, command-line, bash, keyboard

IN windows, I press F6 function key to introduce the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> character that signals the end of file.

```
c:\> copy con filename
```

copies the command line input to the given filename. At the end, after pressing text, I will enter the <kbd>F6</kbd> key which introduces the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>(EOF) character.

1) what is the equivalent command to copy the command line input to a given file ?

2) what key introduces the end of file character in the above command ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. cat > filename
2. you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> and that is EOF

Comment: note: CTRL+D works only in a new line, after pressing ENTER

Comment: also, `cat > filename` works in windows command shell too

Comment: It also works without LF, just press it twice. Same as Linux, really.

Comment: @pqnet OP has asked about MAC not PC. ctrl does not even exist on mac. And also this key combination command + d does not work on mac.

Comment: @Pikachu mac keyboard has CTRL. It is on the left of alt, which is on the left of command. Press ctrl + D, as I said, not cmd + D because that splits the terminal screen